# SQL Server Merge - returning error messages properly - finding record where error occured

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table structure like:

```
Parent
 - Child 1
 - Child 2
 - Child 3
```

In two databases, one of them has some extra fields.

I want to get the data(which can be huge) from one database into another through C# code, so decided to go with SQL Merge.

I have 4 merge statements in a sql transaction 
Merge1- for Parent
Merge2- for Child1
.. for other children
I want to know for which record in parent/child, the insert/update failed.

A simple

```
    BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
    ROLLBACK TRAN trnsn
    SELECT ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH
```

would not suffice. How should I go about this?